# Conditionally create either text or striked through text using ternary

Tags: angularjs

`html` ..

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players">
    <td ng-cloak>{{ player.standing ? player.name : '<strike>' + player.name + '</strike>' }}</td>
    <td ng-cloak>{{ player.associatedNumber }}</td>
    <td ng-cloak>
        <span ng-class="player.standing === true ? 'label label-success': 'label label-danger'">{{ player.standing }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Dataset ..

```
[{
    "name": "Robert C",
    "associatedNumber": 21,
    "standing": true
}, {
    "name": "Joey C",
    "associatedNumber": 55,
    "standing": true
}, {
    "name": "Bobby A",
    "associatedNumber": 15,
    "standing": true
}]
```

This is the first row rendered (others are similiar) ..

[image: screenshot]

Instead I want to render either the player's name as plain text or striked through if they're not `standing`.

Comment: use class and css for style

Comment: one can also try `<s>` tag or `<del>` tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `ng-class` for this. There are two ways of writing a ternary in Angular.

Prior to version 1.1.5

```
<td ng-cloak data-ng-class="player.standing ? 'null' : 'strikethrough'">{{ player.name }}</td>
```

Version 1.1.5 and later:

```
<td ng-cloak data-ng-class="player.standing && 'null' || 'strikethrough'">{{ player.name }}</td>
```

Add the CSS style for `.strikethrough` and everything is good to go.

```
.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

You can see it working at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/MYnXLwCC7XI1MrvcI5ti?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

For Angular 7 you can use ngClass which adds or removes css classes on HTML elements.

.html

```
<td [ngClass]="player.standing ? 'null' : 'strikethrough'"> {{ player.name }} </td>
```

.css

```
.strikethrough {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Read more on `ngClass` [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Answer (score -1):

Try ng-show within ng-repeat

http://jsfiddle.net/z3gg667h/1/

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in players">
    <td ng-cloak>
     <span ng-show="player.standing"> 
    {{player.name}}
     </span>
     <span ng-show="!player.standing">
      <strike>{{ player.name}}</strike>
     </span></td>
    <td ng-cloak>{{ player.associatedNumber }}</td>
    <td ng-cloak>
        <span ng-class="player.standing === true ? 'label label-success': 'label label-danger'">{{ player.standing }}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```