# iterate and strikethrough based on condition

Tags: html, angularjs

I am showing the information in the table using angularjs,html.
 I want to strike through the ID displayed in the second column of the table whose status is "delivered" given in productstatus of $scope.items.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/m0x5TQNY4QprCF5CqRSn?p=preview&preview

I tried as below , but unable to show strikethrough for productID's 10,12 in row1 and 11A,100AX in row3:

```
  <a ng-repeat="pid in item.productid.split(',')" href="https://urladdr/associateid={{associateNum}}" target="_blank">
            <span data-ng-class="item.productstatus.split(',')[$index] === 'delivered' ? 'strikethrough' : 'null'">{{pid}}
            </span><span ng-if="$index+1 != item.productid.split(',').length">;</span>
    </a>
```

json object:

```
$scope.items = [{
  "name":"John",
  "product":"Laptop",
  "productid":"10,11X,12",
  "standing": true,
  "productstatus":{"10":"delivered","11x":"Shipped","12":"delivered"} 
},{
   "name":"Rob",
  "product":"Mobile",
  "productid":"13PX",
  "standing": true,
  "productstatus":{"13PX":"Shipped"}
},{
"name":"Dan",
  "product":"Laptop",
  "productid":"",
  "standing": true,
  "productstatus":null
},{
"name":"Robert",
  "product":"Laptop",
  "productid":"11A,100AX",
  "standing": true,
  "productstatus":{"11A":"delivered","100AX":"delivered"}
  }]
```

Comment: Do you have a class called strikethrough?

Comment: @BShaps - Yes,added in style.css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally create either text or striked through text using ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205161/conditionally-create-either-text-or-striked-through-text-using-ternary)

Comment: I have gone through that. In my case, "productstatus":{"11A":"delivered","100AX":"delivered"} so each productID is mapped with its status and returned as array instead of String.I tried as shown in the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/m0x5TQNY4QprCF5CqRSn?p=preview&preview but could not get it working.

Comment: Oh I see the problem, answer coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to split a json object which you can't do.  If productstatus is changed to a string you can keep your code as is.  Otherwise you'll want to do a ng-repeat with key/value pairs. (i.e. `ng-repeat="(key, prop) in item.productstatus"` or use the key directly i.e. `data-ng-class="item.productstatus[pid] === 'delivered' ? 'strikethrough' : 'null'"`

The following works for me if you want to copy and replace your code:

```
<a ng-repeat="pid in item.productid.split(',')" href="https://urladdr/associateid={{associateNum}}" target="_blank">
       <span data-ng-class="item.productstatus[pid.trim()] === 'delivered' ? 'strikethrough' : 'null'">{{pid}}
       </span><span ng-if="$index+1 != item.productid.split(',').length">;</span>
</a>
```

Updated: added `trim()` based on comments.

Comment: It is failing to strike second one in the row if the condition is matched when i have extra space between productId's as shown in demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/V5vEDidM5cZn2dbec91l?p=preview . I tried using .replace(/ /g,'') but unable to get it work. Any inputs? @BShaps

Comment: try using `pid.trim()`.  `trim()` removes all whitespace from both ends of a string. [trim() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that your data structure of `item.productstatus` is an `Object` and not `Array`.

Therefore you should change the usage to something like that: `item.productstatus[pid]`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/s7ySyexnVrhzSXkY

**Pro TIP**: Use the map to boolean option of `ng-class` directive, it is more cleaner.

```
ng-class="{className: item.productstatus[pid] === 'delivered'}"
```

> The result of the evaluation can be a string representing space delimited class names, an array, or a map of class names to boolean values. In the case of a map, the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element.